# Make text inside flexbox overflow with ellipsis

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I make the text inside the flexbox overflow with ellipsis? I can acheive the goal by wrapping text inside another div. Is there a way to avoid the wrapper?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="flex">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no you cannot avoid the wrapper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333

Comment: and flexbox should not be used for text container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333