# What causes ellipsis not to be shown in css?

Tags: css

What is causing the ellipsis not to be shown, overflow hidden seems to work, but why no ellipsis?

```css
.outer{
    background-color:red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 32px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    width:200px;
}

.inner{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Long long long text, foo bar baz bin<div/>
<div/>
```

Comment: The `display: flex;` inside `.inner`

Comment: Wrapping your text in a `<p>` tag and applying the ellipsis rule to it fixes the issue. Flexbox has multiple overflow related problems ;)

Comment: here is the *why*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333