# Using `text-overflow: ellipsis` with a long, no-space string with `display: -webkit-box`

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

When using `display: -webkit-box` along with the CSS necessary to obtain text overflow ellipsis, the ellipsis disappears.

Here is a working example. Both texts show display ellipsis, but they don't because of the `display: -webkit-box`

https://jsfiddle.net/4wr2dgme/

CSS I'm using:

```
.overflow-class {
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 130px;
  min-width: 130px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 130px; 
}
```

Is there any way I could possibly bypass this problem and have the best of both worlds? I'm using the `-webkit-box` so I can limit the number of lines a div's text has.

Comment: you need extra wrapper

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333