# Ellipsis (three dots) won't show for longer texts

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've set the style as show below.

```
div>span {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For some reason, the threesome for ellipting only seem to effectuate *hidden* and *nowrap* but not *ellipsis*. After some research, I understand it has something to do with the computed available width but I fail to see how it helps me.

Obviously, the width's been exceeded (since the overflowing part is cut off). The closest to working example I've got is when I turn off the display being set to flex. For block it works but not for flex.

I'd really like to use flex as it's resolving sooo many other issues. How can adjust [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ellipting?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.css) so it retains the flex'iness of the display and still ellipses'ify the text?

Comment: explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is with the `display: flex` applied to the `<span>` element you want to add ellipsis to. Changing that to `display: inline-block` or `block` would fix the issue, but I understand why you want to use flex on the span element.

What I suggest is to wrap the label in an additional `<span>` tag. Then apply the ellipsis CSS to the newly created inner span element (Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ellipting-gxesvp?file=src/app/hello.component.css).):

```css
div>span {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div>span>span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span><span>{{caption}}</span></span>
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="{{caption}}"
         [ngModel]="value">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in conjunction with flex-box is demonstrated in the following Example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div>span {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et earum quo tenetur, neque facilis voluptates odio. Neque, facere totam sit!</span>
</div>
```

This was taken from a Post from CSS-Tricks which can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/). Might not be the solution you were looking for but maybe you can work with it anyways.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `display: flex` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the same element, you could do like this:

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100px;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is a block-level element
</span>
```

Comment: *unfortunately you cannot use flex for the span* : this is simply wrong

Comment: I clearified my answer. What I meant was that you can't use display: flex and achieve text-overflow: ellipsis (on the same element), is this false?