# Getting text to overflow while having display:flex

Tags: css, flexbox, display

I am attempting to get text to overflow on this div while having display:flex set. Here is a codepen with the issue I am looking to solve.

```css
.innerPillPlainText {
  display: flex;
/*   display: block; */
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
/*   min-width: 0px; */
}

/* .pillWithHoverByDefault {
 min-width: 0px; 
}
 */
.outerdiv {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div id="Flyout-0" tabindex="-1" class="pillWithHoverByDefault" role="option" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit">
    <div class="innerPillPlainText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/afhassan/pen/vYgxxoN)

When I set `display:block` instead of `display:flex`, it works fine.

I looked around and one of the solutions suggested was to set a `min-width:0px` on the flex child. However, this does not seem to work for me.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333

Comment: and *never* make your text container a flexbox container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333