# text-overflow: ellipsis in a flex label

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Without changing the html** how can I make the text-overflow work correctly in the label:

```css
.outer {
  width: 15em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5em;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        This text is so absurdely ginormous that is surely bound to overflow
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        No overflow here
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If its not possible can you explain why?

Constraining the label width to something like 12em does not work.

PS: if I put the label text inside a span I can easily solve the problem, but that gains me no insight to what I'm doing wrong. Besides the current html is already semantically correct so no further elements should be necessary. Having the input and label be siblings prevents me from styling the input outline when the label is hovered.

Comment: you cannot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x: hidden` works with block elements and you're trying to assign it to a flex container. Just replace `display: flex;` with `display: block;` for your label and it will work. You don't need flex here.

Comment: I need the `display: flex` to align the checkbox with the text.